# Can't find html sub-elements from inside an element

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm somewhat inexperienced in scraping websites with lots of sub elements and am trying to understand the best way to loop through elements that have data you want buried in further levels of sub elements.

Here is an example HTML

```
<div class="s-item__info clearfix">
      <h3 class="s-item__title">The Music Tree Activities Book: Part 1 (Music Tree (Summy)) by Clark, Frances, </h3>
   </a>
   <div class="s-item__subtitle"><span class="SECONDARY_INFO">Pre-Owned</span></div>
   <div class="s-item__reviews">
   </div>
   <div class="s-item__details clearfix">
      <div class="s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary"><span class="s-item__price">$3.99</span></div>
      <span class="s-item__detail s-item__detail--secondary">
      </span>
      <div class="s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary"><span class="s-item__purchase-options-with-icon" aria-label="">Buy It Now</span></div>
      <div class="s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary"><span class="s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost">Free shipping</span></div>
      <div class="s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary"><span class="s-item__free-returns s-item__freeReturnsNoFee">Free returns</span></div>
      <div class="s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

There are multiple items so I started by getting all of them in a list and I can find each title by iterating through but am having an issue getting price. Example code

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("s-item__info"):
    title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//h3')
    print(title.text)
    details = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="s-item__price"]')
    print(details.text)
```

This gets the Title of the item, but can't find the price. If I look outside of "s-item_info" element and just use the driver I can get all the prices with the code below, but wondering why it cant find it in the info element, I would think the details would be a subelement and .// would look through those.

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("s-item__price")
```

Have also tried

```
find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="s-item__detail"]//span[@class="s-item__price"]')
```

I can grab the data I need but want to understand why I can't get the price when I try to iterate through each item. Thanks

Comment: Can you share a link to that page? Also, BTW, `//div[@class="s-item__detail"]` will not work since there is an additional class name there, you should use `//div[contains(@class,"s-item__detail")]` instead

Comment: Ebay https://www.ebay.com/sch/184644/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=textbook&LH_BIN=1&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=1000%7C2750%7C4000%7C5000
Thanks for the response. I have recently tried contains as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("s-item__info"):
    title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//h3')
    print(title.text)
    details = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//following::div[contains(@class,'s-item__details')]//span[@class='s-item__price']')
    print(details.text)
```

Comment: Interesting, this seems to work. I'm guessing following:: does what I thought .// should do by itself. If you are able to give an explanation of what exactly that does and how it's different than .// that would be greatly appreciated. A quick google search makes me think following:: looks for siblings to item but I would have thought the "div class=item__details" was a child of item. Thanks for the help

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that "following::" looks at the siblings of "div[contains(@class,'s-item__details']" searched for from the current node (which is .//). So 's-item__price' and s-item__price' are siblings? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are several problems here:

1. `s-item__info` is not the only class name on that element, you should use
   `//div[contains(@class,'s-item__info')]` instead
2. The first element matching this class name is not a valid search result.
   The simples approach to make your code work can be:

```
for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'s-item__info')]"):
    title = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//h3')
    if(title):
        print(title[0].text)
    details = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="s-item__price"]')
    if(details):
        print(details[0].text)
```

This will print data if existing, otherwise just print empty strings

Comment: 1. Thanks I understand that better now
2. This returns list index out of range which would indicate it is empty I believe

Comment: See the updated answer. Now it should work.