# Looping through nested tree of elements with custom identifiers: usnews scraping

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have looked through other similar questions in the community, but it seems like other instances were a bit simpler. I am trying to scrape usnews.com. [Here](https://www.usnews.com/search?q=oakton%20high%20school#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=oakton%20high%20school&gsc.page=1) is the page I am interested in. I am specifically interested in clicking the first link. I found it in the tree:

```html
<li class="usn-site-search-item">
                <a href="https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&amp;cx=009692862532464842631:ckoj05188pi&amp;q=https://www.usnews.com/education/best-high-schools/virginia/districts/fairfax-county-public-schools/oakton-high-school-20454&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjDtsH14ISCAxXBlokEHYDGC14QFnoECAQQAQ&amp;usg=AOvVaw0e6uaEdQtGvJVlLl9EdIw_" class="usn-site-search-item-link" data-tracking-id="site-search-results-item" data-tracking-placement="1"></a>
                <div class=""usn-site-search-item-container">...</div>
</li>
```

I have tried a simple solution such as

```html
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="usn-site-search-item-heading-link"]/a').get_attribute('href')
```

that doesn't work, of course. However, then I saw iterative solutions, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824114/cant-find-html-sub-elements-from-inside-an-element). How do I implement it in my case, for such an elaborate tree? As of now, it seems like there is a possibility that each search like that on usnews will be custom, which is not going to make scraping worth it all together.

---

Update:

I have tried:

```python
location=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//li[@class="usn-site-search-item"]')
print(location)
for item in location:
    results = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
print(results)
```

This runs, but returns two empty lists `location` and `results`.

Comment: Please provide some output, how does the output like?

Comment: @KunduK For that particular line the selenium doesn't find the element.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't wait properly until item is present in DOM.

If I understood you correct, link item has class `.usn-site-search-item-link`, so you just wait for presence of all elements with this class (or for single element, if you need only 1st link).

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver.get("https://www.usnews.com/search?q=oakton%20high%20school#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=oakton%20high%20school&gsc.page=1")
driver.maximize_window()

waitWD = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
articles = waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.usn-site-search-item-link')))
for article in articles:
    print(article.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I did wait and, just like in many versions of my code, your code returns "TimeoutException: Message: " on my end =(

Comment: @MsTais have you tried to debug? Maybe site is blocking you somehow. Have you tried to use Undetected Selenium chromedriver?

Comment: it seems like there is nothing I can do on this website without being banned... Sorry, I cannot develop it. I wanted to post a new question... See the comment above.

Comment: Maybe moderators can tell me what on earth i did wrong this time X)))) Just interested.